# Effect of multiplication by square root of i

Tags: complex-numbers

The problem requires an explanation of the 'effect' of the multiplication of a complex number, $a + bi$, by $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$ i.e. the positive square root of $i$.

The question was ambiguous with regard to what, precisely, constitutes an 'explanation', but I suspect that the multiplication entails some distinct geometric transformation.

I proceeded this way:
$$\begin{align} (a+bi)\sqrt{i} &= \frac{a+ai+bi+bi^2}{\sqrt{2}}\\ &= \frac{a-b}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{a+b}{\sqrt{2}}i \end{align}$$
I cannot deduce anything further from this result, however, and a quite comprehensive scour of the internet did not yield anything relevant. I would appreciate any opinion on the nature of the 'effect' that the question refers to.

Comment: What's a "positive complex number"?

Comment: I mean to say that $\sqrt{i}= \frac{\pm(1+i)}{\sqrt{2}}$, and that this question refers only to the instance wherein the numerator is positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a rotation to 45 degrees i.e. to $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Any multiplication by a complex number $z = r(cos\phi + i.sin\phi)$ is a rotation to an angle of size $\phi$ and then a multiplication of the original number's norm to $r$ (i.e. to $z$'s norm).
In your case $r=1$ so you're left only with the rotation.

I read a good book about this 20 years ago but it's in Bulgarian only.
Try to google for "complex numbers in geometry".

Comment: So I was seeking $\mathrm{arg} \ \sqrt{i}$? And the transformation is simply a rotation by that value?

Comment: $Arg ( (1+i)/\sqrt2 ) $ Yes, it's a rotation to the argument, correct. You can make a small sketch, try it out on some "small" number e.g. $2+3i$ let's say.

Comment: Yes. I hadn't considered $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$ as a complex number in itself originally. I see now that it is such, with zero real part. Thank you.

Comment: Well, it's real part is $1/\sqrt{2}$, not zero.

Comment: I suppose that it might be given as $0+\sqrt{i}$. Or is this a gross misrepresentation?

Comment: Yeah, it's a signification misinterpretation. It's a bit confusing. For complex numbers avoid the notation $\sqrt{z}$ since it's ambiguous. The $\sqrt {z}$ is a multi-valued function so it's not clear which value you meant when writing $\sqrt{z}$. Both square roots of $i$ have non-zero real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Use polar form for the complex numbers:
$$
\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}
$$

$$z=|z| e^{i\theta}$$

so:
$$
|z| e^{i\theta}e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}=.....
$$